# Select Top 1 from one table and all linked values from another in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables

Table `Tbl_Headline`

```
ID_key
News_Type
```

Table `Tbl_Item`

```
Item_ID
ID_key
```

I need to get the top 1 from `Tbl_Headline` but all the `Item_ID`'s from the second table that match on that `ID_key` in one query

Probably code 101 but I'm having a mental block

Thanks for any help

Comment: `TOP 1` with respect to what? `TOP`, as a rule, ought to be paired with `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've understood the question correctly... Does this help?

```
SELECT
   a.*, b.*

FROM
   Tbl_Headline a
   JOIN Tbl_Item b ON a.ID_key = b.ID_key

WHERE
   a.ID_key = (SELECT TOP 1 ID_key FROM Tbl_Headline)
```

Comment: See @HABO above. ORDER BY what? Without an ORDER BY, the order of the rows cannot be guaranteed.